# StackOverflow Exception using Task Framework

Tags: wpf, vb.net, task-parallel-library, infragistics

I have a Datagrid located on one of my views bound to a collection called "Installed Applications" I create about 1000 of the below tasks. Every time I add to the collection from within a task I receive a stackoverflow exception with no way to debug or see the exception data. I am at a lost and have tried all types of different ways to accomplish what I am trying to do. The thing is I have another function that basically does the exact same thing but doesnt throw an exception.

Non- Working code

```
 Private Sub ViewInstalledApplications(ByVal rec As MuellerAssetModel)
    Dim t As Task = MuellerWMIFactory.CreateNewTaskFactoryJob _
  (Sub()

       If _taskCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested Then

           _taskCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

       End If

       If My.Computer.Network.Ping(rec.IPAddress) Then

           Dim searcherScope As New ManagementScope("\\" & rec.AssetName & "\root\cimv2")

           Dim query As New ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product")

           Dim connectionOptions As New System.Management.ConnectionOptions

           connectionOptions.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Call

           connectionOptions.Username = MuellerWMICrypto.USER

           connectionOptions.SecurePassword = MuellerWMICrypto.PWD

           connectionOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate

           searcherScope.Options = connectionOptions

           Using mosSearcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(searcherScope, query)

               If _taskCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested Then
                   _taskCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

               End If

               Try

                   If _taskCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested Then

                       _taskCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

                   End If

                   For Each prd As ManagementObject In mosSearcher.Get

                       Dim prod As ROOT.CIMV2.Product = New ROOT.CIMV2.Product(prd)

                       Dim mProd As New AssetProduct With _
                           {.AssetLocation = rec.IPLocation, _
                            .AssetName = rec.AssetName, _
                            .Domain = rec.Domain, _
                            .InstallLocation = prod.InstallLocation, _
                            .InstallSource = prod.InstallSource, _
                            .LocalPackage = prod.LocalPackage, _
                            .ProductDescription = prod.Description, _
                            .ProductName = prod.Name, _
                            .ProductPackageName = prod.PackageName, _
                            .StatusMessage = "Call Success", _
                            .WMICallSuccess = True, _
                            .SystemType = rec.SystemType, _
                            .SystemTypeCode = rec.SystemTypeCode}

                       Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()

                                                                      InstalledApplications.Add(mProd)

                                                                  End Sub)
                   Next


                   _installedAppsCount += 1
                   Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                                  InstalledApplicationProgress = (_installedAppsCount / _installedAppsTotalCount) * 100
                                                              End Sub)
               Catch ex As Exception

                   If _taskCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested Then
                       _taskCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

                   End If
                   Dim mProd As New AssetProduct With _
                                                 {.AssetLocation = rec.IPLocation, _
                                                  .AssetName = rec.AssetName, _
                                                  .Domain = rec.Domain, _
                                                  .StatusMessage = ex.Message, _
                                                  .WMICallSuccess = True, _
                                                  .SystemType = rec.SystemType, _
                                                  .SystemTypeCode = rec.SystemTypeCode}

                   Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()

                                                                  InstalledApplications.Add(mProd)

                                                              End Sub)
                   _installedAppsCount += 1

                   Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()

                                                                  InstalledApplicationProgress = (_installedAppsCount / _installedAppsTotalCount) * 100

                                                              End Sub)
               End Try

           End Using

       Else
           If _taskCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested Then

               _taskCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

           End If


           Dim mProd As New AssetProduct With _
             {.AssetLocation = rec.IPLocation, _
              .AssetName = rec.AssetName, _
              .Domain = rec.Domain, _
              .StatusMessage = "Failed Network Ping", _
              .WMICallSuccess = True, _
              .SystemType = rec.SystemType, _
              .SystemTypeCode = rec.SystemTypeCode}

           Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                          InstalledApplications.Add(mProd)
                                                      End Sub)

           _installedAppsCount += 1

           Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                          InstalledApplicationProgress = (_installedAppsCount / _installedAppsTotalCount) * 100
                                                      End Sub)
       End If

   End Sub, _taskCancellationTokenSource.Token)

    _myTasks.Add(t)
End Sub
```

working code different but the same mainly

```
Private Sub ViewAssetRunningApplications(ByVal rec As MuellerAssetModel)
    Dim t As Task = MuellerWMIFactory.CreateNewTaskFactoryJob _
         (Sub()

              If _taskCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested Then

                  _taskCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

              End If

              If My.Computer.Network.Ping(rec.IPAddress) Then

                  Dim searcherScope As New ManagementScope("\\" & rec.AssetName & "\root\cimv2")

                  Dim query As New ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process")

                  Dim connectionOptions As New System.Management.ConnectionOptions

                  connectionOptions.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Call

                  connectionOptions.Username = MuellerWMICrypto.USER

                  connectionOptions.SecurePassword = MuellerWMICrypto.PWD

                  connectionOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate

                  searcherScope.Options = connectionOptions

                  Using mosSearcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(searcherScope, query)

                      If _taskCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested Then
                          _taskCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

                      End If

                      Try

                          If _taskCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested Then

                              _taskCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

                          End If

                          For Each prc As ManagementObject In mosSearcher.Get

                              Dim proc As ROOT.CIMV2.Process = New ROOT.CIMV2.Process(prc)

                              Dim ap As New AssetProcess With _
                                  {.AssetLocation = rec.IPLocation, _
                                   .AssetName = rec.AssetName, _
                                   .AssetProcessNameExec = proc.Name, _
                                   .AssetProcessPath = proc.ExecutablePath, _
                                   .Domain = rec.Domain, _
                                   .SystemType = rec.SystemType, _
                                   .SystemTypeCode = rec.SystemTypeCode, _
                                   .StatusMessage = "Call Success", _
                                   .WMICallSuccess = True}
                              ap.ProcessID = proc.ProcessId
                              ap.PageFaults = proc.PageFaults
                              ap.PageFileSize = proc.PageFileUsage
                              ap.WorkingSetSize = proc.WorkingSetSize
                              ap.ProcessorTime = (CSng(proc.KernelModeTime) + CSng(proc.UserModeTime) / 10000000)
                              ap.Description = proc.Description
                              ap.Caption = proc.Caption
                              If Not proc.IsInstallDateNull = True Then
                                  ap.InstallDate = proc.InstallDate
                              End If
                              ap.ProcessStatus = proc.Status
                              proc.GetOwner(ap.UserDomain, ap.User)
                              If ap.User = "SYSTEM" Or _
                                 ap.User = "LOCAL SYSTEM" Or _
                                 ap.User = "NETWORK SERVICE" Or _
                                 ap.User = "LOCAL SERVICE" Then
                              Else

                                  Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                                                 RunningApplications.Add(ap)
                                                                             End Sub)
                              End If

                          Next
                          Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                                         RunningApplicationsProgress = (_runningAppsCount / _runningAppsTotalCount) * 100
                                                                     End Sub)
                          _runningAppsCount += 1
                      Catch ex As Exception

                          If _taskCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested Then
                              _taskCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

                          End If

                          Dim ap As New AssetProcess With _
                                 {.AssetLocation = rec.IPLocation, _
                                  .AssetName = rec.AssetName, _
                                  .AssetProcessNameExec = "Error", _
                                  .AssetProcessPath = "Error", _
                                  .Domain = rec.Domain, _
                                  .StatusMessage = ex.Message, _
                                  .WMICallSuccess = True, .SystemType = rec.SystemType, .SystemTypeCode = rec.SystemTypeCode}

                          Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                                         RunningApplications.Add(ap)
                                                                     End Sub)
                          _runningAppsCount += 1
                          Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                                         RunningApplicationsProgress = (_runningAppsCount / _runningAppsTotalCount) * 100
                                                                     End Sub)
                      End Try

                  End Using

              Else
                  If _taskCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested Then
                      _taskCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

                  End If

                  Dim ap As New AssetProcess With _
                               {.AssetLocation = rec.IPLocation, _
                                .AssetName = rec.AssetName, _
                                .AssetProcessNameExec = "Error", _
                                .AssetProcessPath = "Error", _
                                .Domain = rec.Domain, _
                                .StatusMessage = "Failed Network Ping", _
                                .WMICallSuccess = True, .SystemType = rec.SystemType, .SystemTypeCode = rec.SystemTypeCode}

                  Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                                 RunningApplications.Add(ap)
                                                             End Sub)
                  _runningAppsCount += 1
                  Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                                 RunningApplicationsProgress = (_runningAppsCount / _runningAppsTotalCount) * 100
                                                             End Sub)
              End If

          End Sub, _taskCancellationTokenSource.Token)

    _myTasks.Add(t)
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any unmanaged code that may be throwing the exception?

Comment: No it is using only managed objects. The thing is when I remove the binding from the grid to the collection it works fine no stackoverflow exception.

Comment: Guess it is something to do with the Infragistics Data Presenter control because if I use xamGrid instead of xamDataGrid the exception doesn't occur.

Comment: That's quite a lot of code, could you simplify it for us? Also, how does the stack trace look like when the exception is thrown?

Comment: It's a stackOverflow exception so the stack cannot be evaluated. I have narrowed down the issue to the datagrid itself has limitations on amount of records it can handle at one time. because the other grid handles it just fine no exception